# Razorpay android SDK integration issue

Tags: android, kotlin, payment-gateway, razorpay

When `order_id` is used in the JSON of checkout object error is occurred

The error that I am getting is this: 
06-23 14:08:44.132 E/PaymentActivity:166: **The id provided does not exist**

This comes in:

```
onPaymentError(code: Int, response: String?, data: PaymentData?)
```

method of PaymentResultWithDataListener

startPayment method is:

```
private fun startPayment(orderId: Long, paymentGateway: PaymentGateway) {
        val checkout = Checkout()
        checkout.setImage(R.drawable.lifcare_logo)
        checkout.setFullScreenDisable(true)
        try {
            val options = JSONObject()
            options.put("name", "Name")
            options.put("description", orderId.toString())
            options.put("currency", "INR")
            options.put("amount", paymentGateway.amount.times(100))
            options.put("order_id", paymentGateway.refTransactionId)

            val prefill = JSONObject()
            prefill.put("email", "EmailID")
            prefill.put("contact", "Number")
            prefill.put("method", paymentGateway.subMethod?.name)

            options.put("prefill", prefill)
            options.put("theme", JSONObject("{color: '#7cb342'}"))
            checkout.open(this, options)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Timber.e(e, "Cannot pay right now!!")
        }
    }
```

ref_transaction_id is:  `"ref_transaction_id": "order_AQjijq5Fj4lg8m"`

When `order_id` is not used then the SDK is working fine. `order_id` somehow is creating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

May i know what number are you using?
It does not work for default number like '9999999999'.

The number should be a valid number.

Comment: It worked.
Razorpay don't give a valid `response` in `onPaymentError ` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add notes key in option parameter as given below:

```
jsonObject.put("order_id", "12345")
jsonObject.put("subscription_id", "50214")
jsonObject.put("user_id", "101")
options.put("notes", jsonObject)
```